# On resume from screensaver, gnome cannot accept keyboard input

Tags: gnome, login, screensaver

I've had this problem for a long while...

First the computer goes into screensaver. Then when it resumes the currently focused window cannot receive keyboard events **of any kind** until focus is lost and then gained again.

Anyone seen something like this/knows why it happens?

As a side note, I always password lock the computer when going into screensaver mode.

Comment: Do you use xneur? If yes, purge it and check the bug.

Comment: @Extender: What is xneur? (I guessing no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s a famous bug on launchpad. It only remains to wait for the decision :(
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/586528

Comment: what makes it famous? Also, can you please incorporate the link into your answer? It is appropriate to edit the answer with more info, as your answer becomes the "definitive" answer vs having to plow through comments.